# C++ using std::find in a map where the key is a custom class

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I'm a C++ newbie and I've been struggling with this for the last couple of days.
I have a task where I need to create a map(unordered or multitable not allowed).
1. Key for the map has to be a class SportTeam and it should have a string country and a string sportsDiscipline.
2. The value for each key is a vector of strings. 
3. After creating the map I should use STL find function to check if any of the keys have Poland as a country.

Here is how I created the map:

```
SportTeam team1{"USA", "Hockey"}, 
team2{"Poland", "Volleyball"}, 
team3{"France", "Running"},
team4{"China", "Swimming"}, 
team5{"Poland","Tennis"};
using  mapVector = std::vector<std::string>;
std::map<SportTeam,mapVector> mapOfTeams;
mapOfTeams[team1].emplace_back("Team Beavers");
mapOfTeams[team2].emplace_back("Team Badgers");
mapOfTeams[team3].emplace_back("Team Snails");
mapOfTeams[team4].emplace_back("Team Doggos");
mapOfTeams[team5].emplace_back("Team Pinguins");
```

This is my header file:

```
class SportTeam {
public:
std::string country;
std::string sportsDiscipline;

SportTeam(std::string newCountry, std::string 
newDiscipline) :
country{std::move(newCountry)},
sportsDiscipline{std::move(newDiscipline)}
{};

bool operator <(const SportTeam& other)const{
    return country < other.country || (country == 
other.country && sportsDiscipline < 
other.sportsDiscipline);
}
};
```

The problem is I have no idea how can I check the class members with find function. I was able to find country when accessing iterator like this

```
mapIt->first.country
```

and then comparing it in if statement in the iterator loop however I cannot replicate this with find function.

I tried following the cpp reference guide for std::find that suggests something like this:

```
auto search = example.find(2);
if (search != example.end()){
...}
```

but it doesn't work if I try it on map itself since it doesn't recognize "Poland". I tried different syntax combinations but the only way I was able to access the country member was when I tried this:

```
auto mapIt = mapOfTeams.begin();
auto search = 
mapIt->first.country.find("Poland");
```

This option doesn't let me compare the result with mapOfTeam.end() as cpp reference suggests as it throws an error for != saying it's an invalid operand.

Any help will be appreciated. I spent quite a long time on stack and other forums but I wasn't able to find solution to my issue hence I decided to gather up my courage and write my first post here :)

TL;DR Key is a class with 2 members (country and sportsDiscipline). I have to use map::find function to check if country = "Poland" and I can't make it work.

Comment: `example.find(SportTeam("Poland"));` - the rules for how many type construction rules c++ will search through is a bit weird.

Comment: You are probably looking for `std::find_if`

Comment: @xaxxon I tried this mapOfTeams.find(SportTeam("Poland")) before but I got an error  "no matching conversion between functional-style cast from const char[7] to SportTeam

Comment: @yedolte you forgot the second parameter to the `SportTeam` constructor

Comment: Use find_if map method with lamda.

Comment: Is there any reason you avoid `std::tie` in the definition of `op<`?

Answer (score 1):

```
mapOfTeams.find(SportTeam("Poland", "Volleyball"));
```

works.

https://godbolt.org/z/K0Akq6

You have to create an object of the key type in order to compare the keys.   You can't construct a SportTeam object based just on a country name, since you require both a country name and discipline.

In order to use a map/hash/dictionary/associative-array efficiently you need to make sure to key them by the thing you want to look them up by.   If you want to look it up by something different (country only), then you'll need to iterate through all the entries searching the country - which is less efficient.

```
for(auto const & sports_team : mapOfTeams) {
  if (sports_team.first.country == "Poland") {
    // do whatever with match
  }
}
```

Or as others have suggested, you can do a `find_if` with a custom comparator, but that's essentially the same code as what I put above - and still not making use of the efficiency of a lookup in a `map`.

Comment: To be a bit nit-picky, this is not what the question asks for. It doesn't say anything about having to specify or know the `sportsDicipline`. This does however work fine if this is an option.

Comment: @super addressed.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It has to be by country only unfortunately. I have two objects that have country as Poland but the disciplines for them are different. The solution should return both objects. The task was to use the find function but as some posts suggest I probably got it confused with find_if

Comment: You know, since C++14 a `std::map` can have a transparent comparator, removing the need to create the key for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need [std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or [std::any_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) where you can have **UnaryPredicate** (or lambda function) to give your comparison logic.

Plenty of examples are available over the internet on how to use this algorithms.